# authlib: InsecureRequestWarning when fetching token

Tags: authlib

I am using a flask client to perform openid authentication. However I get the following warning

```
Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
```

When fetching the token a request is done using requests.Session.requests [here](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/integrations/requests_client/oauth2_session.py#L113).

Adpating the request method of `OAuth2Session` fixes the warning.

```
    def request(self, method, url, withhold_token=False, auth=None, **kwargs):
        """Send request with auto refresh token feature (if available)."""
        if not withhold_token and auth is None:
            if not self.token:
                raise MissingTokenError()
            auth = self.token_auth
        return super(OAuth2Session, self).request(
            method, url, auth=auth, verify=True, **kwargs)
```

Should verification not be enabled by default? Is there a more elegant way to pass verify=True?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass *verify* directly to the methods of the registered RemoteApp when you fetch the token like this:

```
token = oauth.remote_app_name.authorize_access_token(verify=True)
```

I believe SSL verification is enabled by default, however, I use an env var to enable/disable the verification for the requests on a development environment.